# All the knight moves in all the right places

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge

#### Challenge

Find all possible moves for a knight on an empty chessboard.

#### Specifications

1. The first argument is a path to a file.
2. The file contains multiple lines.
3. Each line is a test case representing the position of the knight in CN form.

   - C is a letter from “a” to “h” and denotes a column.
   - N is a number from 1 to 8 and denotes a row.
4. For each test case, print all positions for the next move of the knight ordered alphabetically.

[image]

**Sample Input**

> g2
>   a1
>   d6
>   e5
>   b1

**Sample Output**

> e1 e3 f4 h4
>   b3 c2
>   b5 b7 c4 c8 e4 e8 f5 f7
>   c4 c6 d3 d7 f3 f7 g4 g6
>   a3 c3 d2

[Source](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/180/)

**My Solution**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 5
#define BOARD_LENGTH 8
#define MOVE_BUFFER 24

int rows[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
char cols[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};
char moves[MOVE_BUFFER];
int move_iter = 0;

char num_convert(int *n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (*n == rows[i]) {
            return cols[i];
        }
    }
}

int alpha_convert(char *c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (*c == cols[i]) {
            return rows[i];
        }
    }
}

void add_moves(int c, int n1, int n2) {
    if (c >= 1 && c <= 8) {
        if (n1 >= 1) {
            moves[move_iter++] = num_convert(&c);
            moves[move_iter++] = n1 + '0';
            moves[move_iter++] = ' ';
        }
        if (n2 <= 8) {
            moves[move_iter++] = num_convert(&c);
            moves[move_iter++] = n2 + '0';
            moves[move_iter++] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

char* valid_moves(char position[]) {
    int C = alpha_convert(&position[0]);
    int N = atoi(&position[1]);

    add_moves(C - 2, N - 1, N + 1);
    add_moves(C - 1, N - 2, N + 2);
    add_moves(C + 1, N - 2, N + 2);
    add_moves(C + 2, N - 1, N + 1);

    moves[move_iter - 1] = '\0';
    move_iter = 0;
    return moves;
 }

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File path not provided. Exiting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        puts("Excessive arguments, only the first will be considered.");
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(args[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
        return 1;
    }

    char position[LINE_LENGTH];
    while (fgets(position, LINE_LENGTH, file)) {
        puts(valid_moves(position));
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Joshua: What's the difference?

Computers sometimes have a hard time to differentiate between things that are apples and oranges to us, some examples are:

- if this is a game or if this is real
- thermonuclear war and a game of chess
- `char` and `int`

You have two functions converting from `char` to `int` and back:

```
char num_convert(int *n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (*n == rows[i]) {
            return cols[i];
        }
    }
}

int alpha_convert(char *c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (*c == cols[i]) {
            return rows[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This is not necessary in C, because `char` and `int` are kind of the same thing. You can do regular calculations with characters just like you do with integers. Once in character, stay in character.

So when it comes to playing the game of converting between both types, I'd have to say the only winning move is not to play.

### the mysterious `void add_moves()`

I have no idea what this function does.

```
void add_moves(int c, int n1, int n2) {
    if (c >= 1 && c <= 8) {
        if (n1 >= 1) {
            moves[move_iter++] = num_convert(&c);
            moves[move_iter++] = n1 + '0';
            moves[move_iter++] = ' ';
        }
        if (n2 <= 8) {
            moves[move_iter++] = num_convert(&c);
            moves[move_iter++] = n2 + '0';
            moves[move_iter++] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Why are there two `n` but only a single `c`? What do those values represent?
They are apparently boundary checked, too. Then there's this code block that's pretty much duplicated for both `n`, which is bad.

```
        if (n1 >= 1) {
            moves[move_iter++] = num_convert(&c);
            moves[move_iter++] = n1 + '0';
            moves[move_iter++] = ' ';
        }
```

After all, something is somehow added to `moves`, which justifies the name `add_moves()`. But it's not immediately clear to me what's going on in that function and I feel like too much is going on.

### a hint in `char* valid_moves()`

This function takes away a bit of the mystery from what `add_moves()` is doing. As it calls it with different possible moves of the knight.

```
add_moves(C - 2, N - 1, N + 1);
add_moves(C - 1, N - 2, N + 2);
add_moves(C + 1, N - 2, N + 2);
add_moves(C + 2, N - 1, N + 1);
```

This is not very intuitive. Why do I only see 4 lines here? The knight can do 8 moves in general. Now it is clear why `add_moves()` takes two `n` values as parameters, but only one `c`.

This distribution of logic doesn't appear to be plausible. It's like some part of the movement is calculated in one place while the other happens later. If the concerns of the functions were more clearly separated, it would be easier to understand them.

---

I gave it a try myself. Here's how I did it:

### `Position` type

This is all about positions, so let's create a type for that.

```
typedef struct 
{
    signed char column;
    int row;
}
Position;
```

We're not in oop land, but we still group data together if it belongs together. This helps a lot when passing it around.

> **disclaimer**: I often see type names like `position_t` and I absolutely **hate** that, which is why I'm not using it. Your naming convention may vary.

### relative knight moves as positions

Is 5 meters an absolute position or a difference between two positions? It can very well be both! In the same idea, let's create an array of `Position` that represent the relative movements a knight can perform.

```
Position allKnightMovesInAlphabeticalOrder[] = 
{
    {-2, -1}, 
    {-2, +1}, 
    {-1, -2}, 
    {-1, +2}, 
    {+1, -2}, 
    {+1, +2}, 
    {+2, -1}, 
    {+2, +1} 
};

#define numberOfKnightMoves 8
```

As you can see, `-2` is a perfectly fine `signed char` value. <sup>1</sup>

If you are uncomfortable reusing the `Position` type which from its name might suggest to be an absolute position, you can always `typedef` it to a `Move` type, which makes the intention more clear.

### position check

A handy helper function could solve the sub-problem of whether a certain position is on the board or not.

```
bool positionIsInChessboard(Position *position)
{
    return 
        position->column >= 'a' &&
        position->column <= 'h' &&
        position->row >= 1 &&
        position->row <= 8;
}
```

You need to `#include <stdbool.h>` for `bool`. If you don't want that, you should be able to use `_Bool` as a return type.

### making a move

Another helper function that simply adds two positions together.

```
void addTwoPositions(Position *a, Position *b, Position *result)
{
    result->column = a->column + b->column;
    result->row = a->row + b->row;
}
```

Again, as a `Position` might represent a relative movement, this starts to make sense I hope. If not, recall how a 2D vector in math might represent a fixed point or the difference between two points. This is the same idea.

### putting it all together

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct 
{
    signed char column;
    int row;
}
Position;

Position allKnightMovesInAlphabeticalOrder[] = 
{
    {-2, -1}, 
    {-2, +1}, 
    {-1, -2}, 
    {-1, +2}, 
    {+1, -2}, 
    {+1, +2}, 
    {+2, -1}, 
    {+2, +1} 
};

#define numberOfKnightMoves 8

bool positionIsInChessboard(Position *position)
{
    return 
        position->column >= 'a' &&
        position->column <= 'h' &&
        position->row >= 1 &&
        position->row <= 8;
}

void addTwoPositions(Position *a, Position *b, Position *result)
{
    result->column = a->column + b->column;
    result->row = a->row + b->row;
}

int main ()
{
    Position testPositions[] = 
    {
        {'g', 2},
        {'a', 1},
        {'d', 6},
        {'e', 5},
        {'b', 1}
    };

    int numberOfTestPositions = sizeof(testPositions)/sizeof(Position);

    Position result;

    for(int testPositionIndex = 0; testPositionIndex < numberOfTestPositions; testPositionIndex++)
    {
        printf("%c%d:\t", testPositions[testPositionIndex].column, testPositions[testPositionIndex].row);

        for(int moveIndex = 0; moveIndex < numberOfKnightMoves; moveIndex++)
        {
            addTwoPositions(&testPositions[testPositionIndex], &allKnightMovesInAlphabeticalOrder[moveIndex], &result);

            if(positionIsInChessboard(&result))
            {
                printf("%c%d ", result.column, result.row);
            }
        }

        printf("\r\n");
    }
}
```

I hard coded the test positions into `main()` for brevity. the basic idea for every test case is to iterate over all the possible knight moves, perform them via `addTwoPositions()` and then check the validity of the result with `positionIsInChessboard()`.

I do **not** build up a buffer as you do in your code simply because that isn't necessary.

Here's what I get as a result in terminal:

```
$ ./chess 
g2: e1 e3 f4 h4 
a1: b3 c2 
d6: b5 b7 c4 c8 e4 e8 f5 f7 
e5: c4 c6 d3 d7 f3 f7 g4 g6 
b1: a3 c3 d2
```

---

<sup>1</sup> thanks @[Daniel Jour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/20977/daniel-jour) for pointing out that plain `char` has an unspecified signedness, which may vary across platforms and compilers.

For me, I get the same output for any of the three versions `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char`. It's still good practice to use `signed char` as it makes it more obvious that a `Position` might be a relative position.

Comment: I have much to learn and a fantastic answer to learn from! I'm with you on `Position`'s naming.

Comment: I hope you earn a "Nice Answer" on this one.

Comment: Wow, what a wealth of useful advice here.  This is almost a miniature C tutorial.  :)  (Okay, not really, but it's still great.)

Comment: One note: `char` may be unsigned, which will lead to implementation defined behavior (at best) with your negative offsets. Better play safe and use `signed char`.

Comment: @DanielJour didn't know that, thanks for the comment. I tried all 3 versions and I get the same result for all of them. I still think it improves the code to explicitly declare it to be a `signed char`. See edit.

Comment: Couldn't have said it any better! +1

Answer (score 5):

@I'll add comments tomorrow has covered most of the main points, but I'd also suggest that you consider error scenarios.  With most programming challenges, you can rely on good input however outside of the challenges you need to start thinking about what happens if the input isn't what's expected.

Consider this function:

```
char num_convert(int *n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_LENGTH; i++) {
        if (*n == rows[i]) {
            return cols[i];
        }
    }
    // What happens here?!?
}
```

If the target value isn't found in `rows` before you get to the end of it, then you fall out of the `for` loop at which point the code will return an unspecified value to the caller (you have a similar issue in `alpha_convert`).

Comment: Well spotted. I was just compiling with `make` which just invokes `cc` (aka `gcc`) without `-Wall` (specifically, without `-Wreturn-type`), so I missed that.